# How do I edit the Default Volume?

Tags: wordpress, volume, mediaelement.js

I'd like to set the default audio volume on the wordpress mediaelement.js player to be at 100% volume. It appears that the default is somewhere around 80%.

Can anyone tell me which bit of code I need to change in order to do this?

It'd be great if future versions of Wordpress come with a basic 'Settings' function for the now native player so we can alter thing like default volume and colours.

Comment: Do you have a mediaelement-js-wp.php file?

Comment: Hi Drew, No I couldn't find mediaelement-js-wp.php  
Which folder would I find it in? I did a search locally but got nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Got interested too with that question. So you have to go to your folder like:

> /wordpress/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/

File name:

> mediaelement-and-player.min.js

`Ctrl+F` and search for - `startVolume`

It found me 2 similar results `startVolume:0.8;`
One probably for video and second for audio. So change it from `0.8` to `1`. Then ctrl+F5 on your page and we're done! :)

Comment: Thanks test1n. This worked great but I'll have to remember to do this edit every time wordpress updates. I just wish they would have it set to 1 by default.

Comment: @user2692160 I refuse to use the wordpress media player, because i need to have a playlist and now i'm using Soundcloud iframe playlist instead. You can check it out >[HERE](http://dzvony.org/audio)<

Comment: I used to use that but found it slowed my site down. If soundcloud are having a slow day, you will too. Go native.

Answer (score 2):

Was trying to figure this out and didn't want to edit core files. Inside your theme's `footer.php` file add:

```
<!--Change Wordpress Audio Player Default Volume-->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if($.fn.mediaelementplayer) {
        $("audio").mediaelementplayer({
            success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                mediaElement.setVolume(1.0);
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Just change the `1.0` to whatever you want between 0.1-1.0