# Is there a short code or HTML element to add to set default volume in MediaElement.js?

Tags: jquery, audio, video, mediaelement.js, shortcode

Please bear with Me if I used the wrong terms; VERY new to coding.

By searching this forum on how to add a poster image, I found the following example:

```
    <video id="player1" width="400" height="160" controls="control" preload="none" poster="Youtube.png">      
            <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt6CUH9bVzI" type="video/youtube" />
        </video>
```

I was able to add a poster image simply by adding the element: *poster="url"* to the shortcode using Wordpress' MediaElement.js as follows:

```
     [video width="320" height="240" poster="mysite.com/image.jpg" mp4="video.mp4"][/video]
```

Is there a way to use a similar code and process to set the default volume so that it does not blast at 80%, which is the player's default?

I have tried:

- setvolume="0.3"
- volume="0.3"
- volume="30"
- volume="30%"

I also followed instructions here with no success:

[How do I edit the Default Volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542960/how-do-i-edit-the-default-volume)

My desire is to NOT have a giant logo interfering with the video (e.g., JWPlayer).  I do not wish to purchase plugins that I do not need, since I only use one small video for a demo that will not be used on my site after the event.

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

To set the `volume` of MEJS you have to use the `setVolume(`) property within the `success` API option like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("video").mediaelementplayer({
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            mediaElement.setVolume(0.2);
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/54poewjx/)**

**NOTE**: this won't work if you are using MEJS to play *youtube* videos since not even *youtube* offers a `set` *volume* option as parameter.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ndwnrjtL/)** with *youtube* video.

**Notice** in the fiddle, the `volume` remains the same despite the `console.log()` displays the correct value after changing the `volume`.

Answer (score 0):

To set default volume to mediaelement.js you should create it via javascript.

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('video', {
    startVolume : 0.3
    //any other options separated by ","
});
```

or use jQuery

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    startVolume : 0.3
});
```

[Here](http://mediaelementjs.com/#installation) is full options list(#4) and more examples(#3) from official site.