# How to set the default volume to 100% in WordPress audio player?

Tags: default

I saw that someone else asked this question:

[How do I edit the Default Volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542960/how-do-i-edit-the-default-volume/50159666?noredirect=1#comment87337151_50159666)

But when I tried the 2 possible solutions, it didn't work for me.  I am a novice with code, so I put the code that someone suggested in the theme footer.php  Is there a certain line this needs to be on?  or where specifically in WordPress should I put the code and does someone else have a specific code that will set the player volume to default at 100% and stay at 100% once the audio file plays?  Thanks so much.